# how to check if list has consecutive powers

Tags: ocaml

I am new to ruby and working on a problem but I don't know how to figure it out.
I want to write a function that return true if each consecutive element is a power of the previous element, otherwise return false

for example: if I have a list [2;4;8;16] the function should return true
function should return false , [3; 7; 9;]

```
let consec_ele element = match element with
[] -> true
h::t -> 
if h > t then false
else
  if t/h = 0 && t mod h = 0 then true
;;
```

i just can't figure out how to make it work and that so recursively.

Comment: Why do you write "new to ruby" and tag the question with ocaml (I don't know ruby, it looks like OCaml-Code)?
Did you mean multiple instead of power? because in your example, 8 is not a power of 4! Or did you mean power of the first element?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you first need to formalise your problem :

- if my list is empty, then `true`
- if my list is not, then it starts with a number `n`

  - if `n = 1`, then I need to start again because `a^0 = 1 for all a`
  - if `n > 0` then I call a new function `check` on the rest of the list, `tl`, acting like this :

    - if `tl` is empty, then true
    - else `tl` starts with `n'` then if `n' = n * n` then I call `check` recursively on the rest and I need to keep the fact that I'm now checking for `n * n * n` ...
  - If `n <= 0` then `false`

In OCaml this would be

```
let consec_ele l = 
  let rec cer b = function
    | [] -> true
    | n :: tl ->
      if n <= 0 then false
      (* We can start again for the first 1 we see, but if our
       * list is [1; 1; 1; ...; 1] then we need to stop
       * That's why we have this boolean b which is true and once
       * we see 1 as the head of our list we swap it to false
       *)
      else if n = 1 then b && cer false tl
      else
        let rec check p = function
          | [] -> true
          | n' :: tl -> n' =  pow n p && check (p + 1) tl
        in check 1 tl
  in cer true l;;
```

(For the `pow` function, I let you write it ;-) Of course, this can be bad because you could have an overflow, maybe you'd prefer to see if `n' ^ (1/p) = n` (the pth root of `n'` (why don't we have LaTeX mathmode on stackoverflow ? :-())

Answer (score 0):

Being able to pattern-match on the first two elements in a list makes this trivial. Obviously an empty list is `true`, and a list with one element is also `true`. Otherwise, if we consider the first two elements, if the second is a power of the first, the function is `true`, and we can discard the first and consider the rest of the list recursively. Otherwise, the result is clearly `false`.

```
let rec consec_ele =
  function
  | [] | [_] -> true
  | a::(b::_ as tl) when is_power_of a b -> consec_ele tl
  | _ -> false
```

As a note, your test case of `[2;4;8;16]` should actually return `false` as `8` is a *multiple*, but not a *power* of `4`.

It's very straightforward to handle this lazily using sequences. We need a function to convert a list to a sequence of adjacent pairs.

```
let rec pairs_seq lst () =
  match lst with 
  | [] | [_] -> Seq.Nil
  | a::(b::_ as tl) -> Seq.Cons ((a, b), pairs tl)
```

We also need a function to check if one number is a power of another.

```
let rec is_power_of b n =
  b = 1 || 
  not (n < b) && 
  (b = n || is_power_of b (n / b))
```

Now we can leverage `Seq.for_all`:

```
# let uncurry f (a, b) = f a b;;
val uncurry : ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> 'a * 'b -> 'c = <fun>
# [1; 2; 4; 8] 
  |> pairs_seq 
  |> Seq.for_all @@ uncurry is_power_of;;
- : bool = false
# [1; 2; 4; 16] 
  |> pairs_seq 
  |> Seq.for_all @@ uncurry is_power_of;;
- : bool = true
```